# Displaying comment rating stars in carousel

Tags: comments

I need a solution that will allow users rate page content within a comment.

After that problem comes when I need show that comments(with rating stars) in different spot on my site where I display all of them in a carousel.

for now I have carousel with all needed information(comment author name or piece of comment content) and I'm missing only this rating system implementation:

```
<?php 
    $args_count = array(
        'count' => true
    );
    $comments_query_count = new WP_Comment_Query;
    $comments_count = $comments_query_count->query( $args_count );

    $args = array(
    );
    $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
    $comments = $comments_query->query( $args );

    if ( $comments ) {
        for ($i=0;$i<$comments_count; $i++) { ?>
            <div>
                <div class="a24-carousel-item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php echo get_avatar($comments[$i]->comment_author_email);?>
                        <div class="HERE I NEED stars from specific comment"></div>
                        <p class="author"><?php echo $comments[$i]->comment_author ?></p>
                        <p class="date">Added: <?php echo $comments[$i]->comment_date ?></p>
                        <p class="associated-post"><?php echo get_the_title($comments[$i]->comment_post_ID) ?></p>
                        <p class="content">
                        <?php echo $comments[$i]->comment_content; ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php 
        }
    }
?>
```

Does anyone know a way how to help me displaying comment ratings in my carousel?

Comment: To answer the question we would need to know how the plugin works, [that makes your question be off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); so, you need to ask to the plugin developer if it already has a method to display the ratings or how the ratings are stored in database (I guess it uses comment meta fields); then you will be closer to know how to get them and show them wherever you need.

Comment: i changed question not to focus on plugin but on solution

Comment: Please add the relevant code and explain how the ratings info is stored in the database, that might help other users to suggest a solution.

Comment: After the update, the answer still needs to know the internals of the third party plugin; your question is still off-topic.

Comment: okay, now there is no link to third party plugin. I am looking for solution for my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the *comment rating* is stored in the comment meta, then you can use:

```
$rating = get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'some-meta-key', true );
```

where you need to adjust the `some-meta-key` accordingly.

If the *comment rating* is automatically injected into the comment's text via the `comment_text` filter, then you need to use the `comment_text()` function to display it.

Here's an example:

```
if ( $comments ) {
    foreach( $comments as $comment ) {
        // ...
        comment_text( $comment );
    }
}
```

Note that here you don't need to run `WP_Comment_Query` twice, as you do in your snippet, just to get the number of comments.

There's also a core function for displaying star ratings: [`wp_star_rating()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_star_rating/)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how i can adjust that meta-key? i have to add it first with `add_comment_meta` somehow? how i can add that, using hook or something? im aware of using foreach but later on carousel i need calc if number of comments are even to display it properly.

Comment: Note that `count( $comments )` gives you the comments count. You can e.g. check the `wp_commentmeta` table, ask the plugin author or check the plugin code to see if it's using `add_comment_meta()` @dmnmlk

Comment: aand it works! i found it in plugin code: `add_comment_meta($commentID, 'crfp-rating', $_POST['crfp-rating'], true);` now i took it by `get_comment_meta` and now i have values from 1 to 5 in my carousel. Now i just need display it properly, thanks so much for help and Your time :)

Comment: glad to hear it worked for you @dmnmlk